# Normalization function in R

Tags: r, normalization

I have a matrix I want to transform, such that every feature in the transformed dataset has mean of 0 and variance of 1.

I have tried to use the following code:

```
scale <- function(train, test) 
{   
trainmean <- mean(train)
trainstd <- sd(train)
xout <- test
for (i in 1:length(train[1,])) {
    xout[,i] = xout[,i] - trainmean(i)
}
for (i in 1:lenght(train[1,])) {
    xout[,i] = xout[,i]/trainstd[i]
}

}
invisible(xout)

normalized <- scale(train, test)
```

This is, however, not working for me. Am I on the right track?

Edit: I am very new to the syntax!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the built-in `scale` function for this.

Here's an example, where we fill a matrix with random uniform variates between 0 and 1 and centre and scale them to have 0 mean and unit standard deviation:

```
m <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol=4)    
m_scl <- scale(m)
```

Confirm that the column means are 0 (within tolerance) and their standard deviations are 1:

```
colMeans(m_scl)
# [1] -1.549004e-16 -2.490889e-17 -6.369905e-18 -1.706621e-17

apply(m_scl, 2, sd)
# [1] 1 1 1 1
```

See `?scale` for more details.

To write your own normalisation function, you could use:

```
my_scale <- function(x) {
  apply(m, 2, function(x) {
    (x - mean(x))/sd(x)
  }) 
}

m_scl <- my_scale(m)
```

or the following, which is probably faster on larger matrices

```
my_scale <- function(x) sweep(sweep(x, 2, colMeans(x)), 2, apply(x, 2, sd), '/')
```

Comment: Thank you. This is homework, and therefore I tried to write out a function myself, but I will most likely use the build-in function, since I have already used too much time writing my own.

Answer (score 2):

Just suggesting another own written normalizing function avoiding `apply` with is from my experience slower than matrix computation:

```
m = matrix(rnorm(5000, 2, 3), 50, 100)

m_centred = m - m%*%rep(1,dim(m)[2])%*%rep(1, dim(m)[2])/dim(m)[2]
m_norm = m_centred/sqrt(m_centred^2%*%rep(1,dim(m)[2])/(dim(m)[2]-1))%*%rep(1,dim(m)[2])

## Verirication
rowMeans(m_norm)
apply(m_norm, 1, sd)
```

(Note that here row vectors are considered)

Comment: I can't work out what is centred (and subsequently scaled) here. Neither row vectors nor column vectors have means close to 0, nor variance close to 1. Is there a typo here? My matrix algebra is pretty sketchy, but I'd like to see it work :)

Comment: sorry I forgot the division by `dim(m)[2]`each time, modified now

Comment: ok there might have been some misplaced `(` as I wrote that without R; this is fixed now

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for persevering. I had suspected you were unable to test it earlier.